# djvulibre-3.5.27 Build Error

Tags: compiling, gcc, error-handling, djvu

I am currently on **Linux Mint 18.3**. I downloaded the package from the Djvulibre [website](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/).

Here is my error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/amucs/Downloads/djvulibre-3.5.27/desktopfiles'
PNG      16x16/mimetypes/djvu.png
convert: delegate failed `"rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
convert: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-85016muix9LZjKWV': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-85016muix9LZjKWV': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/540.
convert: no images defined `16x16/mimetypes/djvu.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
Makefile:604: recipe for target '16x16/mimetypes/djvu.png' failed
make[2]: *** [16x16/mimetypes/djvu.png] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/amucs/Downloads/djvulibre-3.5.27/desktopfiles'
Makefile:418: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/amucs/Downloads/djvulibre-3.5.27'
Makefile:349: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Your best hope is to take it up with their dev team.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem compiling djvulibre-3.5.27 on my Linux Mint 18.3 system, but figured out that during the build process make was attempting to run the "rsvg-convert" program to convert a PNG icon file, but this program wasn't available on my system. I installed it using "sudo apt install librsvg2-bin", restarted the build process and everything worked just fine. BTW, when I read the djvulibre-3.5.27 distribution "NEWS" file, I noticed that the djvulibre developers switched from imagemagick's "convert" command to rsvg for generating icons in version 3.5.23. In fact, it looks like configure did check for icon generating software, printing: "Icon generation....: convert". After installing librsvg2-bin, configure printed: "Icon generation....: rsvg", so it looks like it was checking for the presence of "rsvg-convert". I'm not sure why the build process didn't originally fall back to using imagemagick's "convert" when it detected that "rsvg-convert" was not installed.